# Why I am seeing the Promise is pending

Tags: promise

I have below piece of code used to play sound. When I run it in FireFox (version 75.0) debugger. It shows Promise pending. I do not see Pending in Chrome (79.0.3945.117).

Can some please explain I am doing it correctly. I hope it won't cause any memory leak.

```
 playSound = function (url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var audio = new Audio();
            audio.preload = "auto";
            audio.autoplay = true;
            audio.error = reject;
            audio.onended = resolve;
            audio.src = url;
            audio.play();

        });
    }

playSound('http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3').then(function(response) {
console.log("Sound played Successfully.");
}, function(error) {console.log("Sound Failed.", error);}
)
```

---

I tried event this examlple. I still see Promise Pending in Firefox:

```
testFunction = function () {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   if (true) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});
}

testFunction().then(function(response) {
    console.log("Success::", response);
}, function(error) {
    console.log("Failure::", error);
})
```

Am I doing something fundamently wrong?

Comment: @Rashomon - They have hooked up resolve and reject to the `.error` and `.onended` properties.  Since I can't find the interface for the Audio object they are using, I don't know if those properties do what they want.

Comment: If you can post a link to the Audio object interface you're using, we could probably help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about an [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) and the interface on that...

The `.error` property is not at all what you want.  It's not an event handler, it's a property you read so assigning to `reject` won't do anything useful.

The `HTMLAudioElement` inherits most of its properties from [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) which shows you should be using the `error` and `ended` events like this.  Run the code snippet, then press the "play" button to see it work.

```js
function playSound(url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var audio = new Audio();
            audio.prelopad = "auto";
            audio.autoplay = true;
            audio.addEventListener("error", reject);
            audio.addEventListener("ended", resolve);
            audio.src = url;
            audio.play();

        });
    }

var button = document.getElementById("play");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var url = 'http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3';
 playSound(url).then(function(response) {
    log("Promise resolved. Sound played Successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    log("Promise rejected. Sound Failed.");
  });
});

function log(x) {
   let logger = document.getElementById("log");
   let div = document.createElement("div");
   div.innerHTML = x;
   logger.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div>
Press the Play button to start the audio<br><br>
<button id="play">
Play
</button>
</div>

<div id="log" style="margin-top: 20px;">

</div>
```

Comment: In my case I do not need a button or any interface for the user to interact with. My code  continusely update data on the page. If certain condition is met then audio sound is played.

Comment: @hamid - The button is just for the purpose of the demo. You can call your function anytime after the page has loaded.  This shows you how to properly resolve your promise which is what you asked.

Comment: @hamid - Did this answer your question?

Comment: jfriend00 --Thanks for your help. Your code works perfectly. But some how Firefox still shows Promise ->pending but it does print "Promise resolved. Sound played Successfully." So I believe the promise is getting resolved. Probably its how FF deal with promises.  Since you are adding addEventListener, do you think it need to be removed (removeEventListener) after Event is handeled?

Comment: @hamid - Where does is show promise pending?  In what line of code?  You don't need to remove the event listener here because in the code you show, the audio object is not used any more and will be garbage collected.

Comment: @hamid - If this did answer your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.